# Loading image SVG and getting Content Security Policy (CSP) error

Tags: html, svg, content-security-policy

I'm trying to load SVG images and get a CSP error as follows:

[image]

I keep getting the error event when I added the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you can see tells you that the `img-src` was not set and it fallbacks to `default-src` even though that you have added `meta` tag with your *CSP* values.

This behaviour can be observed when the *CSP* header is already set via `HTTP`. You have to choose whether to set it via HTTP or as `meta` tag.